# Can I convert text boxes saved in a PSD file to be editable once opened in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, text, typesetting

I have created a PSD file which has a large amount of text boxes.

I then placed that file in an InDesign document and now I am required to make all the text editable.

Is there a quick way of solving this or do i need to physically re-write or copy and paste the text in InDesign?

Answer (score 3):

### No

You have editable text layers in your PSD file.

If you need editable text in your INDD file, you need to hide all text layers in the PSD and manually re-create all text objects in INDD.

PSD files placed in INDD are treated just like any other raster asset, with the notable difference that you can turn PSD layers on & off when placing in INDD.

No, there is no 'click here to convert PSD to INDD text boxes' button.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering whether perhaps there was a way around it. I'm not too familiar with other Adobe so wondered if perhaps i opened the PSD file in an Illustrator or anything else it would allow me to place the file in InDesign and make the text editable that way?

Comment: @KamilaKudlata It **is** possible at times to open a PSD with AI and have editable text. But *nothing* will do the same when moving to InDesign from *any* other application.